# VueUse OnClickOutside with teleport

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vueuse, teleport

I want to close the modals if the user clicks outside the modal. But the modal uses the `<teleport>` component to be rendered in the `<body>` element.

How can I prevent closing when there is clicked inside the modal?

```js
<OnClickOutside @trigger="moreInfo = false">
    <div v-if="moreInfo" class="absolute top-100 right-0 bg-white z-20">
        <update-time-slot-modal :timeslot="timeSlot" @update="updateTimeSlot"/>
        <delete-time-slot-modal @delete="deleteTimeSlot(timeSlot.id)"/>
    </div>
</OnClickOutside>
```

```js
<teleport to="body">
    <!-- modal -->
</teleport>
```